# Spring-data-jpa NativeQuery with two output params

Tags: java, spring, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data

I use oracle stored procedures with spring-data-jpa. In the most cases it is pretty well, when it is a function or output parameter is first in the param list. But I have some stored procedures with ouput param is the last in the param list:

```
procedure get_data (some_val in varchar2 cur out sys_refcursor);
```

or returns more than one output refcursors like

```
procedure get_my_data (cur1 out sys_refcursor, cur2 out sys_refcursor, some_val in varchar2);
```

Is it possible with any way to use it with JpaRepository?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I've found answer by myself :)

My situation is a good point for using spring-data's [Custom Implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) 
You should:

1. Create Interface, named YourRepository**Custom** with your new
   method (for example EmployeeRepositoryCustom)
2. Create an imiplementation for this interface with name
   YourRepository**Impl** (for example EmployeeRepositoryImpl)
3. Inside method implementation you can use
   SimpleJdbcCall for calling Oracle stored procedure, for example
4. ...
5. PROFIT!!!

Note: naming rules are important if you want to use default configs

Answer (score 1):

well,
if you want a localized call to a StoredProc from a service or utility class, then you can use Spring Jdbc for StoredProc. See below for implementation

```
public class StoredProcSampleTest extends StoredProcedure {
private static final String SPROC_NAME = "HH_EXTRACT.SAMPLE_TEST";
public StoredProcSampleTest(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource, SPROC_NAME);
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("v_in_msg", Types.VARCHAR));
    declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("v_out_msg", Types.VARCHAR));
    compile();
}

public  String  execute() {
    HashMap<String, Object> hmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hmap.put("v_in_msg", "Suresh");
    hmap.put("v_out_msg", "");
    Map<String, Object> results = execute(hmap);
    String outRes = (String) results.get("v_out_msg");
    return outRes;    
}
```

}

now in your utility class or Service class, do this

```
    protected StoredProcSampleTest storedProcSampleTest;


@Autowired
public void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
    this.storedProcSampleTest = new StoredProcSampleTest(dataSource);

}
```

:

```
public String callStoredProcSampleTest(){
    return storedProcSampleTest.execute();
}
```

Comment: I found it useful for PostgreSQL *procedure* calls, I only had to add "call " to procedure name and override `isSqlReadyForUse()` function. Stored *functions* work on PostgreSQL with JPA/Spring Data out of the box.